# Notify users when their [approved suggested] edit is rolled back

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, notifications, rollbacks

I'm currently going through a particular user['](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5469991/piyush-jaiswal)s suggested edits, most of which have been accepted by nincompoops, and which do only silly things like code-formatting `arbitrary phrases` and *adding* thanks.

I'm encountering one or two instances in which someone's beaten me to it, but it occurs to me that the editor probably never finds out. As far as he's concerned, almost all his suggestions get accepted so nothing's wrong, right?

If he were notified that an edit were rolled-back (or rolled-over?) then he'd have an opportunity to look at the edit reason and eventually realise that there's probably a reason his 3.514e11 edits are being nuked from orbit and that he should probably stop being such a doofus.

It's a shame we can't trust our reviewers to get this right, but there we go.

Comment: FWIW I also flagged for mods to possibly have a delicate word with him.

Comment: Please tell me you also flagged the reviewers. It sounds like review suspensions are in order.

Comment: Is this related to the recent post on MSO?

Comment: @Laurel: What recent post is that?

Comment: @S.L.Barth: I wanted to but sadly I don't have _that_ much time. I'm hoping the mods going through the guy's edit history may see fit to do so.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit [Warm Regards](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322020/how-to-stop-minor-edit-binging-warm-regards-rampage#comment338668_322020)

Comment: The particular user responsible for this won't be suggesting edits for a while, and I'm handing out review bans like candy. They probably would have been banned from suggesting edits with one or two more rejections, but there were a bunch of OP-accepted edits that circumvented review rejections or reviewers who edited the suggestion but forgot to tick the "reject" option.

Comment: @Brad: mmmm candy

Comment: @Laurel: Nope, not him.

Comment: OT, but it's burning a hole in my brain: I've duckduckgo-ed, I've tried translating it into scientific notation and 1337, but I still can't work it out: 3.514e11? What does 3.514e11 mean?

Comment: @stib I'd assume it means 3.514 x 10^11. That is, the number 351,400,000,000. I'd further assume this was a hyperbolic way of saying, "This user suggested a very large number of very crappy edits."

Comment: Oh,  ok.  I was thinking that this was a reference that everyone on the internet understood but me, like 90% of the stuff on the internet.

Comment: Yeah it's how my fingers fell on the number pad with a 'e' thrown in for good measure.

Comment: Why oh why can't we give bounties to meta posts. Pure gold this is +500.

Comment: I've had a few new users who've rolled back my edits, even though they're 100% correct. When I ask them what was the issue, they simply say they were trying to do something else and don't know how the system works. However, I detected such rollbacks on revisiting the question. Thus, I might have missed other rollbacks. If I was notified about them, I could at least be sure that such mistakes by new users won't happen and won't spoil the quality of content on a SE site.